# Wordpress Ajaxify Problem with Scroll-to

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to ajaxify my Wordpress with this gist: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

However I'm having some issues to make the Scroll-To script work. All my scripts are enqueued in my function.php as you can see below. I also checked if the file of the Scroll-To JS were loading in the source code and yes it is. The main menu of my website (in the front end) is always in fixed position, so when I scroll the content then I click a link in the menu, it opens the page at the same scrolled position.

Here is how the scripts are loaded:

```
function load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

   wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '20151215', true );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll-to', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll-to.js', array(jquery), '', true );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'history', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/history.js', array(), '', true );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array(jquery), '', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot!